# Configure automatic update of base class properties whenever derived class is updated EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a base class called EntityBase which is used on every entity modeled in this project. This base class uses the Repository Pattern to perform operations on theses entities as shown below.

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly EfCoreContext _dbContext;

    public Repository(EfCoreContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }


    public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : EntityBase
        => _dbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

    public IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : EntityBase
        => Filter<T>(predicate).AsQueryable<T>();

    ...
    ...

    public T Add<T>(T entity) where T : EntityBase
    {
        _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return entity;
    }
}
```

And here's the Base Class

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public EntityBase()
    {
        this.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        this.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        this.CreatedBy = "DC";
        this.UpdatedBy = "DC";
    }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

How do I use the Fluent API or Data Annotations to automatically capture the UpdatedOn and UpdatedBy properties of the EntityBase whenever any one of it's derived classes are updated?

Here is my DbContext

```
public class EfCoreContext : DbContext
{
    public EfCoreContext(                             
        DbContextOptions<EfCoreContext> options)      
        : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void
        OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BookConfig());       
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BookAuthorConfig());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderConfig());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LineItemConfig());   
    }
}
```

Comment: have you extended `EntityBase` on every entity? or are you trying to use reflection?

Comment: @kimbaudi. Extended.

Answer (score 0):

First: You probably shouldn't have two repositories. EF is already a generic repository with a UoW called DbContext. Read more about it [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/122683).

If you can live to wait until `SaveChanges` is called, you could overrite your DbContext's `SaveChanges` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is EntityBase && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        var entity = (EntityBase)entry.Entity;
        //do something
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I recognize that the repository is an unnecessary layer of abstraction. Will probably look to move away from it in future iterations. In the meantime I think this solution will definitely be work. Thanks.